# What exactly is the returned data type for a particular std::bind?

Tags: c++, boost, c++11, std

First I have to say I have to know the returned data type from std::bind.

I have a struct which is defined as

```
typedef struct
{
  UINT ID;
  CString NAME;
  boost::any Func;// 'auto' doesn't work here
} CALLBACK;
CALLBACK CallBackItems[];
```

Func is a function holder, I want it to hold different kinds of callback function.

Somewhere I initialize CallBackItems like this:

```
CallBackItems[] =
{       
    { 1,    L"OnReady",       std::bind(&CPopunderDlg::OnReady, pDlg)           },
    { 2,    L"CustomFunction",std::bind(&CPopunderDlg::OnFSCommond, pDlg,_1,_2) }   
   //...................    more items here         
};
```

When I try to use the 'Func' in each CALLBACK I have to cast it first and then use it like a function. So far I tried:

```
 //CallBackItems[0].Func is binded from pDlg->OnReady(), pDlg->OnReady() works here,
   boost::any_cast<function<void()>>(CallBackItems[0].Func)();

   ((std::function<void()>)(CallBackItems[0].Func))();
```

none of them work, anybody knows how to cast the returned variables from std::bind?

Comment: `std::function` can hold them.

Comment: std::function is a template, you can't use it as a generic type in a enmu. Here if you replace boost::any with std::function, there is compile errors.

Comment: Well, trying to store functions that take different numbers of parameters is also a problem. Now you need to have a way of calling them with the right arguments.

Comment: `First I have to say I have to know the returned data type from std::bind.` First I have to say _no, you don't_. :)

Comment: `boost::any Func;// data type auto doesn't work here` It's possible that you've misunderstood what `auto` is; it's certainly not a data type.

Comment: maybe 'auto' is better here than data type 'auto', Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The type returned from `std::bind` is unspecified:

> #### 20.8.9.1.3 Function template bind [func.bind.bind]
>
> <sup>1</sup> ...
>
> `template<class F, class... BoundArgs>`
>     *unspecified* `bind(F&& f, BoundArgs&&... bound_args);`

You can use `std::function` to store them, e.g.

```
void f( int ) {}
std::function< void(int) > f2 = std::bind(&f, _1);
```

In your case, this mean you could need to cast the type when you store the result from `std::bind`:

```
CallBackItems[] =
{     
    { 1, L"OnReady", std::function< void() >( std::bind(&CPopunderDlg::OnReady, pDlg) ) },
    { 2, L"CustomFunction", std::function< void(int,int) >( std::bind(&CPopunderDlg::OnFSCommond, pDlg,_1,_2) ) },                  
};
```

and then get it back with:

```
boost::any_cast<std::function<void()>>(CallBackItems[0].Func)();
```

Comment: Because Func's data type has to be 'auto' in the enum. I can't store them as a specific data type.

Comment: @Giswin See my updated answer. Also: What "enum"? Do you mean the array or structs?

Comment: Sorry, it is a array of struct.

Comment: @Giswin: There is no such data type `auto`. `auto` is a keyword that allows for type deduction in the presence of an initialiser. It's not a magic bean that allows you to store any arbitrary object, like `boost::any`.